# How can I relate 2 entities (Product and Cart) to make a Cart functionality in a RESTful API with Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, prisma

I'm trying to make a Shopping cart logic in a RESTful API, I'm working with Node.js (TypeScript), Express and prisma, but I'm no sure if my prisma schema should be like this:

```
model Product {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  description String?
  price       Int
  imageUrl    String?
  stock       Int      @default(1)
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  cartItems   CartItem[]
}

model Cart {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  items     CartItem[]
}

model CartItem {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  quantity  Int
  product   Product  @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId Int
  cart      Cart     @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id])
  cartId    Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

Any ideas to improve this?

I tried to add CartItem model, but I'm not sure if it's a correct approach

Comment: The improvement could be in the database design, but the current relation (SQL/Prisma speaking) it's correct

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I just was having some issues of how to create the endpoints for those entities